# AWS: Unable to open custom TCP port (1880) on EC2 instance despite adding Security Group rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a beginner in AWS and I'm trying to open a custom TCP port (other than HTTP/80) on my EC2 instance. I've followed the steps below, but the port doesn't seem to be open:

I navigated to the Security Group associated with my EC2 instance.
I created a Custom TCP rule with the following details:
Protocol: TCP
Port range: 1880
Source: 0.0.0.0/0 (to allow access from any IP address)
This is similar to the default HTTP rule for port 80.
However, when I try to verify if the port is open using the nc -vz  1880 command, it fails. The same command works fine for port 80.

Any ideas on what I might be missing or doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `nc -vz` tests if the remote server accepts connections. Is there actually a service or web server listening on port 1880 and accepting connections?

Comment: Hi Jarmod, thanks for your input. The person who originally had the issue informed me that they didn't resolve the problem with port 1880 but switched to using a default HTTPS port instead. So, it seems there might have been no service listening on port 1880. Appreciate your help!